# Agrupar datos de columnas de un datraframe según el valor de otra columna otra columna con Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

he intentado agrupar un dataframe con Pandas intentando que los valores de las columnas A y C se calulen sus promedios por grupos según la columna B:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [23,4,13,15,23,31,41,25,25,22,33,53,23,48,49,54,55,58,96,16],
                   'B': [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6],
                   'C': [1,4,3,1,3,3,1,2,5,2,3,5,3,4,9,4,5,8,6,6]})
# Veríamos esto: 
     A  B  C
0   23  0  1
1    4  0  4
2   13  0  3
3   15  1  1
4   23  1  3
5   31  1  3
6   41  1  1
7   25  2  2
8   25  2  5
9   22  2  2
10  33  3  3
11  53  3  5
12  23  3  3
13  48  4  4
14  49  4  9
15  54  5  4
16  55  5  5
17  58  5  8
18  96  6  6
19  16  6  6
```

Al calcular esos promedios las filas con el mismo numero en B quedarían totalmente repetidas (Es lo que busco), luego borraría esas repetidas.

Resultado buscado (pr seria el promedio calculado):

```
     A  B  C
0   pr  0  pr
1   pr  1  pr
2   pr  2  pr
3   pr  3  pr
4   pr  4  pr
5   pr  5  pr
6   pr  6  pr
```

Para intentarlo hice:

```
df.groupby(by=["B"]).mean()
```

Como vi que no funcionaba, lo que hice fue pasar la columna B como string (pensandome que si agrupaba por nombres lo conseguiria:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].astype(str)
df.groupby(by=["B"]).mean()
```

Tambien he probado con:

```
df.groupby(by=['B'], dropna=False).mean()
df.groupby("B", group_keys=True).apply(lambda x: x)
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo del todo lo que se busca, ya que tu primer intento de usar `groupby()` sobre la columna B es la solución correcta y produce de hecho los promedios de cada grupo de las otras dos columnas. Este es el resultado en tus datos de ejemplo:

```
>>> df.groupby(by=["B"]).mean()
           A         C
B                     
0  13.333333  2.666667
1  27.500000  2.000000
2  24.000000  3.000000
3  36.333333  3.666667
4  48.500000  6.500000
5  55.666667  5.666667
6  56.000000  6.000000
```

Por ejemplo, vemos que para B=0 A sale 13.333 que es el promedio de 23, 4 y 13, los valores de A para el caso B=0, y para C sale 2.666 que es el promedio de 1, 4 y 3, los valores de C para esas filas en que B=0. El resto de filas también muestran los resultados esperables.

Quizás lo que no te gusta es que la columna B haya "desaparecido" del dataframe y en cambio haya aparecido como índice. Esto es normal al hacer un `groupby()`, las columnas por las que se agrupa se convierten en índice.

Puedes deshacer eso utilizando `.reset_index()` sobre el resultado, lo que convierte el índice en una columna "normal" (y añade un nuevo índice que comienza en 0). La nueva columna que resulta de esta acción se llamará "B" en este caso, justo lo que querías, pero se insertará como primera columna, por lo que el resultado tendría ahora las columnas en orden B, A, C.

Si las quieres en el orden original basta que las selecciones de nuevo en el resultado especificando el orden deseado.

Poniendo todo esto junto:

```
columnas_originales = df.columns
resultado = df.groupby(by=["B"]).mean().reset_index()[columnas_originales]
print(resultado)
```

Y se obtiene:

```
           A  B         C
0  13.333333  0  2.666667
1  27.500000  1  2.000000
2  24.000000  2  3.000000
3  36.333333  3  3.666667
4  48.500000  4  6.500000
5  55.666667  5  5.666667
6  56.000000  6  6.000000
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo que intentaba. Pero a pesar de que el código era correcto, me faltaba en primer lugar esto que has propuesto para organizar el index, pero luego he tenido un fallo muy absurdo (que solo me he podido dar cuenta al ver tu respuesta), pero me faltaba hacer el print con un nuevo df a partir del anterior `df2=df.groupby(by=["B"]).mean()` o siguiendo tu ejemplo de código.